# React js rendering my site with error on logs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error at first render of every page of my site:

Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'disableContextMenuCheckOnAllIFrames')
at chrome-extension://jifcoadedkediabkmjbflemiblmnbjfk/content/centrify-idle.js:1:9034

When I inspect the source, it shows me the error with a red cross (❌) at the level of the  tag.

I have researched, and found that it may be because I am trying to access a property while not defined, or there is an error in the flow of my asycn functions... but then it suggests a problem with an extension of chrome.

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Yeah, maybe disable extensions in your Chrome one by one until the error disappears.

Comment: This is happening from CyberArk Identity Browser Extension. Remove this extension or disable it for localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening from CyberArk Identity Browser Extension. Remove this extension or disable it for localhost.

Comment: I wasn't getting that error before... any idea as of why now?